# how to make my own distro

Tags: custom-distributions

I want to make my own ubuntu based distro which contain some moste usable software. and I want to it be bootable and I can give it to my friends to install it on their pcs!
but I don't know how do this.
and I checked the website of remistersys but it doesn't load.

what I have to do?

Comment: Start here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd/49679#49679 :)

Comment: I have a big problem and it's that I cant download anything from google code so I can't download from this: http://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/downloads/list   and so what I have to do???

Comment: please, review the two answers below. UCK might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Ubuntu Customization Kit is a tool that helps you customizing official
>   Ubuntu Live CDs (including Kubuntu/Xubuntu and Edubuntu) to your
>   needs. You can add any package to the live system, for example
>   language packs, or applications.<sup>1</sup>

To download and more info see [UCK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/).

Also may also find some good information on how to create your own distro [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-build-your-own-linux-distro).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graphical tool [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/) to create your own custom Ubuntu Live CDs:

> Why customize LiveCDs?
>
> You may wish to customise the Ubuntu Desktop LiveCd to:
>
> 1. make your own Linux / Ubuntu distribution
> 2. [...]

Read more of the documentation and step-by-step process at:

- [Ubuntu Help: LiveCD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)
- [How to customize Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/a/49679/94697)